# NSURL fileUrlWithPath method returns double path

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, nsurl

this is the scenario:
In a sandboxed app for OS X 10.10.5 I have some path saved in NSString object, say **@"file:///Users/xxx/**".

Then I execute `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:object]`. That gives me NSURL object like this

> @"file:/Users/xxx --
>   file:///Users/xxx/Library/Containers/com.123456.App/Data/"

.

I only need this part **@"file:///Users/xxx/Library/Containers/com.123456.App/Data/"**

Somehow the source string is twisted and doubled and extra dashes added in the middle.
Can anyone explain why does it happen?

Xcode 6.4

Comment: My guess is it is something to do with how you have constructed the string path. Can you show us what you are doing there..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*fileURLWithPath:*   will return a file URL path.

i.e starting with:  **file:///**

This means that the string path that you pass it should be in the form of:

```
@"/Users/xxx/Library/Containers/com.123456.App/Data/"
```

You do not need to prepend the path with **file:///**. Or you will get the result that you are getting.

---

Example:

```
NSString * stringPath = @"/Users/xxx/Library/Containers/com.123456.App/Data/";

    NSURL * anUrl =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath ];


     NSLog(@"nUrl %@",anUrl);
```

----> *nUrl file:///Users/xxx/Library/Containers/com.123456.App/Data/*

Comment: Or, if you start with a URL string, which is what `@"file:///Users/xxx/"` is, use `+URLWithString:`.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try something like this? By giving fileName and extension.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"fileExtension"]];
```